# How to print the result of a void type method into a file with Java PrintWriter

Tags: java, file, methods, call, printwriter

I'm doing exercise work for my Java programming course, the question goes as so:

Write a method called printTree that outputs to a file a triangle of asterisks based on the height value passed to the procedure.  Test this method in the main method.

- E.g.  Triangle of height 3 should output to a file called file14:

I'm just not sure how to write the void return to the file that I've made in the main method. I'd like to minimize the importing of any other java.io methods aside from FileWriter, but any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class OutputToFile14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        //Creating PrintWriter
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("file14.txt");
        
        //writing method output to file
        output.write(printTree(4));
        
        //saving file
        output.close();
    }

    public static void printTree (int height) throws IOException{
        
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if (j < i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can either have the `printTree` method use the `output` variable directly (pass it as a a parameter) or have the `printTree` return a String

Comment: If the instructions are as you say they are, you don't *return* any result, but rather you write to the file within the method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels would i instead then write the printwriter statement in the method?

Comment: Creating a variable then outputting it in the function is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Four observations. `System.out` is a **`PrintStream`** (and you could pass a `PrintStream` to your method). `try-with-Resources` allows you to eliminate explicit `close()` calls. Using `System.getProperty("user.home")` allows you to write into the home folder directly (which can be handy). And use `j < i` instead of `if (j < i)` in your inner loop. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (PrintStream output = new PrintStream(
            new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "file14.txt"))) {
        printTree(output, 4);
    }
}

public static void printTree(PrintStream out, int height) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            out.print("*");
        }
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Also, since Java 11,

```
public static void printTree(PrintStream out, int height) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        out.println("*".repeat(i)); // You might want "*".repeat(1 + i)
    }
}
```

Comment: A better answer -- thank you

Comment: I'm not too well versed with sending in an object as an argument to methods, but I'm assuming similar to the other response, this basically makes it so its all "one-lined": declaring the file, naming it. and then it being in a print stream makes it so its sendable as an argument? I'd love to hear some clarity points, My course is f in the early stages of writing to file so I'd love to understand more

Comment: [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html). You can construct your own `PrintStream` instances. To write to a `File`. With this [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)). As for *sending an object as an argument*, `main(String[] args)` (it's the very first thing you do). Hope that helps.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you! I think this will end up requiring more research work on my end but, I think I'll be guided in the right direction. Thank you for that main header fact, something I did not know, but now do. Much appreciated

Answer (score -2):

You could solve it like this

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class OutputToFile14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        //Creating PrintWriter
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("file14.txt");
        
        //writing method output to file
        output.write(printTree(4));
        
        //saving file
        output.close();
    }

    public static String printTree (int height) throws IOException{
        String output = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if (j < i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    output += "*";
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            output += "\r\n";
        }
        return output;
    } 
}
```

This is a somewhat ugly way to solve it quickly.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class OutputToFile14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        //Creating PrintWriter
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("file14.txt");
        
        //writing method output to file
        //output.write(printTree(4));
        printTree(4, output);
        
        //saving file
        output.close();
    }

    public static void printTree (int height, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException{
        
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if (j < i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    pw.write("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            pw.write("\r\n");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate greatly your answer! I think I'm going to stray away from this though sorry, as I don't really know how to work with the PW as a parameter for future reference. Thank you though, much appreciated.